# Can Django's Replace be used to replace multiple substrings at once?

Tags: python, django

In Django, I can have queries that look like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Replace

MyModel.objects.update(description=Replace("description", Value("old_1"), Value("new_1")))
MyModel.objects.update(description=Replace("description", Value("old_2"), Value("new_2")))
```

The first `.update` will go through the database, look for the "old_1" substring in the description field, and replace it with the "new_1" substring. The second `.update` call will do the same thing for the `old_2` substring, replacing it with the `new_2` substring.

Can this be done in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the [**`Replace`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#replace) twice:

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Replace

MyModel.objects.update(
    description=Replace(
        Replace('description', Value('old1'), Value('new1')),
        Value('old2'),
        Value('new2'),
    )
)
```

We can make a utility function to build such expression:

```
from functools import reduce

from django.db.models.functions import Replace


def MultiReplace(expr0, *kvs):
    return reduce(lambda e, kv: Replace(e, *kv), kvs, expr0)
```

Then we can nest these with:

```
MyModel.objects.update(
    description=MultiReplace(
        'description',
        (Value('old1'), Value('new1')),
        (Value('old2'), Value('new2')),
    )
)
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a cleaner way to do this? If you have like 10 substrings you'd like to replace, the nesting would get pretty crazy very quickly.

Comment: @John: yes, we can define a "fold"/"reduce" pattern for this. See update.